# Build multipart/form-data using Java and without Apache libraries

Tags: java, multipartform-data

I have a java code that builds a multipart/form-data and it all works OK but when the text part is in cyrilic it becomes unreadable on the server side.

The reason this happens is because the DataOutputStream class doesn't handle cyrilic character except if i use its method .writeUTF but then two additional bytes are added the again this makes me some trouble on the server side.

Here is the beggining of the code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
```

Then the text bytes and image bytes are written to the dos object and finally we have

```
bos.toByteArray();
```

Do you know what else i can use instead of **DataOutputStream** and **ByteArrayOutputStream**.

Comment: OkHttp3 has a useful Multipart entity builder

Answer (score 1):

`DataOutputStream` has no proper way to write `Strings` in specified encoding, but if you can't switch to e.g. `BufferedWriter/OutputStreamWriter`, you can use the `write(byte[] b, int offset, int len)` as follows:

```
byte[] bytes = myString.getBytes("UTF-8"); // or whichever encoding you want
dataout.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: 10x. i will try

Comment: However if you're just writing Strings and not using the other methods of `DataOutputStream`, then you should go for a `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "UTF-8"));` instead.

Comment: i am writing an image bytes as well as. its a multipart form